# Rails5 + Paperclip: Image_tag for a collection of images displays whole image array

Tags: erb, ruby-on-rails-5

Models:

```
Place has_many Photos
Photo belongs_to Place
```

I wan to find and display all photos that belong to a place.

Controller:

```
@place = Place.find(params[:id])
```

view:

```
<% if @place.photos.exists %>
    <%= @place.photos.each do |place| %>
        <%= image_tag place.photo.url(:medium)%>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Id displays requested photos - but also whole photo array:

```
[#<Photo id: 1, place_id: 6, title: nil, status: nil, description: nil, photo_file_name: "IMG_0436.JPG", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 4751995, photo_updated_at: "2016-10-19 22:11:35", created_at: "2016-10-19 22:11:38", updated_at: "2016-10-19 22:11:38">, #<Photo id: 2, place_id: 6, title: nil, status: nil, description: nil, photo_file_name: "IMG_0427.JPG", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 5683007, photo_updated_at: "2016-10-19 22:13:21", created_at: "2016-10-19 22:13:24", updated_at: "2016-10-19 22:13:24">, #<Photo id: 3, place_id: 6, title: nil, status: nil, description: nil, photo_file_name: "IMG_0428.JPG", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 4957508, photo_updated_at: "2016-10-20 19:42:56", created_at: "2016-10-20 19:42:58", updated_at: "2016-10-20 19:42:58">]
```

How to display only images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are outputting the `@places each`

change

```
<%= @place.photos.each do |place| %>
```

into

```
<% @place.photos.each do |place| %>
```